# Why is Kendo UI DatePicker not passing value to JSP on form submit via POST?

Tags: jquery, forms, jsp, kendo-ui

I'm building a JSP Form that includes a Kendo UI DatePicker on it.  For some reason the date is not getting to the JSP controller with the request.getParameter function.  It only comes across as null.  How do I fix this issue?

I've searched Stackoverflow, Kendo UI support and Google.  I've tried a few variations, but without success.  I've tried different browsers and dev environments.

The form section that includes datePicker:

```
<table class="vipTable">
    <tr>
        <th class="strong" colspan="3">Time Frame</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date Req <input type="text" name="dateReq" id="dateReq" size="10" value=""/><BR>(mm/dd/yyyy)</td>
        <td>Expected Start Time <input id="startTime" name="startTime" title="startTime" value="8:00 AM"/></td>
        <td>Expected Completion Time <input id="endTime" name="endTime" title="endTime" value="10:00 AM"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The JS used to setup the datePicker so that:
- Only Sundays are active and only future Sundays are selectable
- Disable keyboard input; force use of datepicker calendar

```
// create DatePicker but ensure that only Sundays can be selected - present and future Sundays).  
//That is, if today is Sunday, it is selectable in addition to future Sundays.
    var presentDate = new Date();
    var dayOfWeek = presentDate.getDay();

    if(dayOfWeek != 0) {
      // day of week is not Sunday
      presentDate.setDate(presentDate.getDate() + ( 7 - dayOfWeek));

    }

    var dd = presentDate.getDate();
    var mm = presentDate.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = presentDate.getFullYear();

    if (mm < 10) {
      mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    var closestSunday = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

    $('#dateReq').attr("value", closestSunday);

    $('#dateReq').kendoDatePicker({
        value: presentDate,
        min: presentDate,
        disableDates: ["mo", "tu", "we", "th", "fr", "sa"],
        change: function() {
            var value = this.value();
            $("#dateReq").attr("value", kendo.toString(new Date(value), "d"));

        }
    }).data('kendoDatePicker');

    // Disable manual input on this field, force use of calendar.
    $("#dateReq").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

JSP Code trying to get the datepicker value

```
String dateReqString = request.getParameter("dateReq");

            if (MY_LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                MY_LOG.debug("formattedDate: dateReqString = " + dateReqString);
            }
```

Error message in the log

```
[WebContainer : 7] DEBUG {} ITOutageSubmitController - formattedDate: dateReqString = null

 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1450)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:375)
    at com.kmbs.itsform.portlet.controller.ITOutageSubmitController.handleActionRequest(ITOutageSubmitController.java:57)
```

Note, line 57 in ITOutageSubmitController is trying to use the dateReqString value from the dateReq parameter, but it is null.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was an embarrassingly simple fix.  ***Disabled inputs do not get submitted.***  Commenting out the line that disabled it fixed the issue.  However, I *do* want the input field disabled, so I created a new hidden input field which gets the datepicker's date value on change and the controller grabs that value instead.